# Cannot access local or remote web.config

Tags: c#, iis, file-permissions

I have created a an application that installs a few webservices into IIS, sets SSL/removes SSL, configures them , refresh app Polls and then tests if they are working.
All is working as it should, but on one client its is throwing a

> Unable to access the configuration system on the remote server. Make
>   sure that the remote server allows remote configuration.

This error message is generated whenever I call the following method,

```
public static System.Configuration.Configuration GetConfigurationFrom(string appName, string hostName, string site)
        {
            return System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(@"/" + appName, site, null, hostName);
        }
```

I have tried the following :

- Give myself access to the wwwroot folder
- Give everyone access to that folder
- Tried to access it from a remote location
- Tried to access it from a local client
- Enabled remote connections in IIS's Management Service

All of the above give me the above error, only on this one environment and I am not sure what could be causing this. Is there anyway I can determine the issue, thanks in advance.

Comment: "To obtain the Configuration object for a remote resource, your code must have administrative privileges on the remote computer." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.openwebconfiguration?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_Configuration_WebConfigurationManager_OpenWebConfiguration_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_String_ The account that runs your app simply fails to meet the requirement.

Comment: The apo is running as administrator on that machine

Comment: It must also be the administrator of the machine whose name matches "hostName".